# How do I control the filesystem where Kafka Streams puts it's data

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I have a Kafka Streams application, it works great, but it seems that rocksdb puts the data into /tmp. How do I tell kafka (rocksdb) where to place the data. /tmp is no good for a production application

Answer (score 0):

You can set configuration parameter `state.dir`.

Cf the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html

Answer (score -1):

You can change the path of `log.dirs` variable in the `server.properties`.I would suggest you to go through the following link to learn something more on this.

http://www.openkb.info/2018/09/how-to-dig-into-kafka-streamsksqls.html

Comment: The question is about Kafka Streams, not the Kafka brokers.